# struct - understanding code

Tags: c++, struct

I am trying to understand the below struct.
What is happening in line 3-8 ?
Line 17 has struct with no name. What does that do ?
Thank you.

```
1.  struct ImageData
2.  {
3.      bool operator<(const ImageData& in_Other)
4.      {
5.          if(Year < in_Other.Year)
6.              return true;
7.          if(Year > in_Other.Year)
8.              return false;
9.  
10.         return false;
11.     }
12. 
13.     int Width;
14.     int Height;
15.     short   Year;
16.     
17.     struct
18.     {
19.         unsigned ThumbFileOffset;
20.         unsigned ThumbContainerIndex;
21.         unsigned ThumbImageSize;
22.     } Thumbnails[6];
23. };
```

Comment: Do you not understand the `bool` type?

Comment: Lines 17-22 define an array of 6 elements, each of which is of the anonymous type defined by the `struct { … }` notation.  You can't create any other variables of that type; it has no name.  (Lines 7 and 8 are redundant; line 10 would suffice without them.)

Comment: I understand the bool data type. I have read several c++ tutorials on creating a struct and they do not discuss the use of an if statement. They only show a list a variable initializations. I need a more advanced tutorial. Could someone suggest a tutorial on struct that is more advanced ? Thank you.

Comment: The body of `ImageData::operator<()` could be rewritten to simple `return Year < in_Other.Year;`.

Answer (score 1):

The function *overloads* the operator `<` so that you can compare `ImageData` objects using the `<`.

The function uses the `Year` member when comparing.